# How can I generate vertex groups for this mesh?

Tags: armature, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

I have a mesh with an armature and animation, but unlike all the other models I got from this source, this mesh doesn't have vertex groups.

[image]

In this 231-frame animation, the model should start out as a robot and transform into a truck.  At the final animated frame, the armature is in alignment with the mesh:

[image]

But the mesh has no vertex groups:

[image]

I have tried parenting the mesh to the armature using automatic weights, but this is all that happens:

[image]

I also get an error message at the bottom: "Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find a solution for one or more bones"

Envelope weights start out the same way, but badly distort the mesh when the animation is played.  How can I get Blender to recognize which parts of the mesh should correspond to the correct bones?

Comment: Maybe it's only parented to one bone, please share your file

Comment: You can check the export and import first, maybe some options were missed during the process. What file format are you importing?

Comment: Here's my file: https://www.mediafire.com/file_premium/3folcxfot2huanv/bulkhead_error.zip/file

Regarding the import process, it's in FBX format.  I'm using a plugin called Better FBX Importer/Exporter, but the same thing happens with the native Blender FBX importer.  I've checked the file in Noesis, and the same thing is happening, so I don't think it's an import problem.

Comment: You need to create vertex groups that have the same name as the bones that are supposed to control them and assign them to the correct parts of the vehicle, I don't see any other solution

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid that would be the case.  Thanks.